# Single button toggle for audio using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple button to turn on and off my audio file.

Once I click play I can't turn it off.

I'm using an image as my button and `div.onclick` to spark the function.

The html `audio` tag has id `audioPlay`.

I use the global boolean `playSound`, initially set to `false`.

My script looks like this:

```
var playSound = false;
if (playSound != true) {
    audioButton.src = '../../testStuff/audioPlay.png';
    audio.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('audioPlay').play();
        playSound = true;
        console.log(playSound);
    }
}

if (playSound == true) {
    audioButton.src = '../../testStuff/audioStop.png';
    audio.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('audioPlay').pause();
        playSound = false;
    }
}
```

When I click on it the first time it works fine. It sets `playSound` to `true`.

However, when I go to click it a second time, nothing happens. Something is setting `playSound` back to `false` and I don't know why.

I've tried switching the `==true if` statement above the `false` one, as well as rolling both `if` statements into a single `onclick` function but it still operates this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the entire code block? Is what you posted inside of an event handler?

Comment: Are you using html5 audio tag to play the audio? Look at the source for this prototype: http://www.scottandrew.com/pub/html5audioplayer/

Comment: I'm not using the audio player just <audio> tags, i want to control the start and stop with a single button.

This is just the audio portion of the code block.  I'm using javascript to generate a page when another portion of my website is clicked.  The audio button is part of the generated page.  Should i use event whistlers instead of the div.onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're adding two separate click handlers that are both being executed on each click. This results in `playSound` always being set to `true`, but then immediately being set back to `false`.

Instead, write a function called `togglePlay` that does something like the following, and set that as your click handler, but only once.

```
    function togglePlay () {
      if (playSound) {
        audioButton.src = '../../testStuff/audioStop.png';
        document.getElementById('audioPlay').pause();
        playSound = false;
      } else {
        audioButton.src = '../../testStuff/audioPlay.png';
        document.getElementById('audioPlay').play();
        playSound = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: ahhh thanks!  I'm such an idiot/weirdo, i never liked using else statements and now i realize how stupid that is.  I take it when adding the else it goes through the entire block and executes based off the parameters of the if statement, instead of executing both if statements.  So what was causing the problem is the click would happen, do the first if statement, switch to true, and then jump to the next if statement and reset itself false?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it a little more, your variable is set to `false`, so when the script is loaded, the if statements are evaluated and only the one event handler is added, but it always has the same result. It changes the value of `playSound` to `true` the first time, but continues to set it to `true` on each click event after that. The only time the if statements are evaluated is when the script first loads. After that, it's just executing the code inside the first if statement on each click.

Answer (score 0):

```
//play is the name of the botton that u click to play the music and psuse    
const isplay;
play.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    const playmusic = ()=>{
        isplay = true;
        console.log('play music');
        music.play();
    };
const pausemusic = ()=>{
isplay = false;
music.pause();
};
if(isplay){
pausemusic();
}else{
playmusic();
};
)};
```

Comment: this is the simple way  to do it and it is work ...try it